# Create LESS variable from HTML content

Tags: html, less

I wasn't able to find a thread on this, but if there is one, please let me know!

I want to create and use LESS variables based on the HTML content in a certain tag.

For example, the HTML would be something like:

```
<div class="bar">
    <span>80%</span>
    Blah blah
</div>
```

And the CSS/LESS would be something like:

```
@width: '$(".bar > span").text()';
.bar { background: red; width: @width; }
```

Do I need to convert the variable from a string to an int or float in order for it to be used as such? And if so, how?
Thanks!

Comment: Why are you using HTML with LESS? LESS should be compiled to CSS...

Comment: I don't think this is possible. The LESS is unaware of your html, and jquery doesn't process within your LESS.

Is there a reason you're not setting @width directly in the LESS?

Comment: @nvioli Well, it is possible if you run less.js client-side. But indeed, if one needs to set element width using jquery he *just sets* element width with jquery right via CSS. No reason for the LESS to be involved there at all.

Comment: Even if possible (interfacing LESS with html requires client side compiling, and so what you ask may theoretically be possible), it would be _highly_ inadvisable. What happens if someone comes along and changes the html to `Blah hahahah`? Then you end up with `width: Blah hahaha` (i.e `width: auto`).

Comment: What I ultimately was trying to accomplish was setting this percentage once, somewhere, and reusing it everywhere. Hence, why LESS variables got involved at all, and I wanted to not use JS if possible. At first, I was trying to to just use a LESS variable for the sizing, and then set it as the HTML content using the CSS content tag, but it was working. Not using JS was more or less a design challenge for me, I could use it if I had to :P

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if your comment above was mistyped,

> "At first, I was trying to to just use a LESS variable for the sizing,
>   and then set it as the HTML content using the CSS content tag, but it
>   was working."

You state "but" after which I expected "it was [not] working" (otherwise, I would have expected you to say "and"). That was actually a solution I thought of, but if I am correct, and it was *not* working for you, then my guess is you were using content incorrectly (directly on the `span` itself?). The `content` property is [only valid](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/content) on the `::before` and `::after` pseudo elements.

So this works like you originally intended (and no need for the `span` element at all):

**LESS**

```
@width: 80%;

.bar {
  background: red;
  width: @width;
}

.bar:before {
  content: '@{width}';
}
```

**CSS Output**

```
.bar {
  background: red;
  width: 80%;
}
.bar:before {
  content: '80%';
}
```

### [See Example Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/pK6z5/)

This will work fine for IE8 (you note supporting that in another comment). Assuming the `80%` is not a necessary "content" value (that you want search engines picking up because it is critical data on the page), then using a pseudo element is perfectly fine for such visual user feedback. If you desire, it can be [aligned just as regular text and some padding added to space it from the surrounding text](http://jsfiddle.net/pK6z5/1/), just like it were a `span` element.

Answer (score 0):

As said in the comment i doubt less can do this.

Although you might want to use the meter HTML5 tag like so

```
<meter value="2" min="0" max="10">2 out of 10</meter><br>
<meter value="0.6">60%</meter>
```

Here is an example

http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml5_meter

I think this is what you wanted to achieve from your script.

Comment: This is fantastic, but I have to support IE unfortunately; specifically IE 8. But I might be able to work around it....maybe.

Comment: You can use this and have a javascript workaround for the rest. do something like the following `$(".bar").css("width" , $(".bar > span").html())`